# Use values from JSON response as variables on webpage. Ajax API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a ajax call my my API which returns some JSON. I would like like to use certain values from the JSON to dynamically update my webpage.

```
<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Role"></div>
<div class="Location"></div>
<div class="Team"></div>
```

I know I have my response data here `success: function(data)` but I am unsure on how to call the values I want and then put them into variables I can use on my page.

For example on my page `<div class="Name"></div>` should show `john smith`in plain html.

**HTML With Ajax Call**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>1</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Role"></div>
<div class="Location"></div>
<div class="Team"></div>

<script>
var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
function myapiRequest(endpoint, method, options) {
    $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { // my successfully reutnred json
},
    url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
myapiRequest('/users/12345G?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams'); // this will be a variable 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Response**

```
{  
   "user":{  
      "name":"john smith",
      "email":"jsmith@myapi.com",
      "time_zone":"Asia/Hong Kong",
      "color":"crimson",
      "billed":true,
      "role":"user",
      "description":null,
      "invitation_sent":false,
      "contact_methods":[  
         {  
            "id":"55666655",
            "type":"email_contact_method",
            "summary":"Work",
            "html_url":null,
            "label":"Work",
            "address":"team13@myapi.com.com",
            "send_short_email":false,
            "send_html_email":true
         },
         {  
            "id":"55554555",
            "type":"email_contact_method",
            "summary":"Work",
            "html_url":null,
            "label":"Work",
            "address":"team31@myapi.com.com",
            "send_short_email":false,
            "send_html_email":true
         },
         {  
            "id":"5455555",
            "type":"email_contact_method",
            "summary":"Work",
            "html_url":null,
            "label":"Work",
            "address":"team12@myapi.com.com",
            "send_short_email":false,
            "send_html_email":true
         },
         {  
            "id":"5444555",
            "type":"email_contact_method",
            "summary":"Work",
            "html_url":null,
            "label":"Work",
            "address":"team41@myapi.com.com",
            "send_short_email":false,
            "send_html_email":true
         }
      ],
      "teams":[  
         {  
            "id":"232656TM",
            "name":"team1",
            "description":null,
            "type":"team",
            "summary":"team1 support",
            "privilege":null
         },
         {  
            "id":"25656TM",
            "name":"team1",
            "description":null,
            "type":"team",
            "summary":"team1 support",
            "privilege":null
         },
         {  
            "id":"P767676TM",
            "name":"team1tt",
            "description":null,
            "type":"team",
            "summary":"team1 support",
            "privilege":null
         }
      ],
   }
}
```

Comment: Why does your response have `**` around it? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: So data(response) represents the entire object. As you can see, the only key available in the object is `"user"`. To access that, you can do `data.user`. That will return the object that is the value of user. If you just wanted the user name, you could do `data.user.name`. If you wanted something from a single contact method, you would need to loop like this `$(data.user.contact_methods).each(function(){});` and in that add logic to filter out the unwanted results. Make sure the object returned isn't in JSON string format, other wise you need to call `JSON.parse()` on whatever is stringified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which specific fields you want to use for location and team but this is the idea ..

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
    $('.Role').html(data.user.role);
},
```

You can add the extra two lines to map your JSON response to `.Location` and `.Team`

Comment: How would I call something more complex, say from my response, after 'Teams' -  "id":"25656TM",? Thanks

Comment: Something like data.teams[0].id

Comment: Sorry Chris,    $('.teams').html(data.teams[0].id ); doesn't return anything.

should return 232656TM from my example above should it not?

Comment: Actually, looking at the JSON it should be data.user.teams[0].id

Answer (score 0):

you can get the element by classname

```
var userName = document.getElementsByClassName("Name");
```

then

```
userName [0].innerHTML = data.user.name;
```

and put this code inside you success callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

**1)**  Give your interesting parts of the HTML unique identifiers like

```
<div id="name"></div>
```

**2)** Get a reference to the HTML element you want to modify. With jQuery you can easily get a hold of individual elements in your HTML like so

```
const $nameElement = $('#name'); // # is for id
```

The "#" part is called a selector. [There are tonnes of different selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that are useful in different circumstances.

**3)** Manipulate the element. In your case, give it some inner HTML value.

```
$nameElement.html(data.user.name);
```

[There are a lot of different convenience methods for different types of manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) as well.